# ASP.Net Core - EntityFrameworkCore data is not adding, updating instead

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using ASP.Net Core 2 and Entity Framework Core with MySQL.

I want to add a simple entity to the database.

My Model is like this-

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured fluent API in DBContext like this-

```
//Key automatic generation configuration
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
   .Property(b => b.Id)
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

And then calling from controller to add content like this-

```
Employee employee = new Employee
{
     City = newString,
     Department = newString,
     Name = newString,
     Salary = DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond
};

_context.Employee.Add(employee);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

What I am seeing is updating the first data having *ID = 1* and never add new data. I want my ID to be auto-incrementing and don't want to use GUID for maintaining ID. What do I need to do to make it work?

### Update-

I have already tried-

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

And
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

And

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

But no luck.

The complete code is in [***this*** **Github** *Repository*](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/ASP.NetCore-MySQL-Login-CRUD).

And the controller is **[here](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/ASP.NetCore-MySQL-Login-CRUD/blob/master/InventoryManagement/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L25)**.

Comment: Is auto increment set up on the column in the database?

Comment: Sounds like provider bug. Which provider are you using? in any case, `Add` should not generate `UPDATE`, turn on EF Core [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) and take a look at the executed commands.

Comment: What you have should work. In fact, none of the fluent config or data annotations are actually required. There's something else going on not shown in the code you've chosen to post. I'd recommend posting a more complete example of your code, specifically a small reproduceable sample.

Comment: My complete code is given in here- https://github.com/AbrarJahin/ASP.NetCore-MySQL-Login-CRUD

Comment: And controller is given here- https://github.com/AbrarJahin/ASP.NetCore-MySQL-Login-CRUD/blob/master/InventoryManagement/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L25

Comment: Can you please have a look @CrishPratt

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I am having the same issue, but only one one of my tables.  All the others work properly, and they are all coded to use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity in the model.  And it was working properly, until my last publish.  Nothing has changed with the code used by the insert code, and I can't find where it is actually generating the update. :( frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation "DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity" for auto-increment.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Migration File should be generated as below:

```
CreateTable(
      "dbo.table",
      c => new
      {
        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        .............
      })
      .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: Can you please give me another approach @Mittal

Comment: I understand that you need auto-increment column as ID, Is anything else also you want to achieve?

Comment: Have you created migration file, It should be looks like as update in above naswer?

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing data annotations and fluent api configurations which is not a good practice. anyway, entity framework considers int Id in persistence models as key in general so you don't have to specify it manually. I recommend you choosing only one approach (from my experience fluent api is usually better - more extensible for future and persistence models look much cleaner) and try to go without specifying that the Id should or should not change because without it you will get what you want.

your migration should look like this:

`migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
     name: "TableName",
     columns: table => new
     {
         Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
             .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", 
             SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
     },
     constraints: table =>
     {
         table.PrimaryKey("PK_TableName", x => x.Id);
     });
...`

Comment: if you want you can link a github repo and I will have a look at it

Comment: It is already given, repo address is - https://github.com/AbrarJahin/ASP.NetCore-MySQL-Login-CRUD/blob/master/InventoryManagement/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L25